# How to implement SAML SSO in React native?

Tags: react-native, single-sign-on, saml

I have some details of SSO,

```
SAML attributes returned by IDP: (using my account as an example )
mail : urn:oid:0.9.2357.13254323.145.2.6
(user@gmail.com)
uid : urn:oid:5.8.5468.34689645.460.5.6
(username)
cn : urn:oid:7.89.567.8.678923.6.5.879
(Display name; User, Name)
hKIEdAccountType : urn:oid:3.56.67.6.674345.8.4.3
(staff/students/others - depends on the role )
 
metadata from IDP could be found here:-
Nidpdev:
https://example.com/abc/def/metadata <- testing IDP
NIDP:
https://example.com/abc/defp/metadata <- production IDP
 
 
LOGOUT:
Development IDP
Using GET to https://example.com/abc/def/logout
Using POST to https://example.com/abc/def/slo
 
Production IDP
Using GET to https://example.com/abc/def/logout
Using POST to https://example.com/abc/def/slo
```

I have a React Native app, I want to implement SSO in the app, but I am not sure how should I implement in the app. I don't find resources.

I am expecting some details about implementing SAML SSO in React native, any example app would be fine.